# how to resolve stringIndexOutofBoundsException when bitmap is initialized

Tags: libgdx

I am learning to develop a game using libgdix.I follow the book Learning LibGDX game development,second edition.
I am getting stuck on using Bitmapfont.

```
public class AssetsFonts
{
    public final BitmapFont defaultSmall;
    public final BitmapFont defaultNormal;
    public final BitmapFont defaultBig;
    public AssetsFonts()
{
        defaultSmall = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/arial-15.fnt"),true);
        defaultNormal = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/arial-15.fnt"),true);
        defaultBig = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/arial-15.fnt"),true);
        defaultSmall.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        defaultNormal.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        defaultBig.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear,TextureFilter.Linear);
    }
}
```

when i run this am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file: images/arial-15.fnt
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:650)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:465)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:115)
at com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.game.Assets$AssetsFonts.<init>(Assets.java:125)
at com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.game.Assets.init(Assets.java:49)
at com.packtpub.libgdx.canyonbunny.CanyonBunnyMain.create(CanyonBunnyMain.java:22)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -7
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1918)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:476)
... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you've got is [this one](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.java#L656). Practically saying that something went wrong while loading the file. The inner exception shows what went wrong while loading:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -7
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1918)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:476)
```

Since there's no call to String#substring [at line 476](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.java#L476), this is an indication that you're using an older version of libgdx (which is to be expected, because [a lot has changed to that file](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commits/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.java) recently). So I'd suggest that you update to the latest nightly (or check the github history at the time of the version you're using), so you know which call is actually causing the error.

Either way, the fact that a substring call failed while loading your file is a good indication that the file is likely to be corrupt or doesnt meet the expected format in another way. Assuming you want to use the font that the libgdx tests uses, then you can download the correct version [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libgdx/libgdx/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/arial-15.fnt) and the required image [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libgdx/libgdx/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/arial-15_00.png). Make sure to place the image in the same folder as the fnt file.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my project to 1.6.3 version.now it was running successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem is that it can't find the font file...

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file: images/arial-15.fnt
```

Make sure the file is in the correct place, which is probably `android/assets/images` but depends on your project setup.

Also ensure that your run the desktop version with android/assets as the working folder.

Comment: I checked it ,the file is in the correct place what else could be the problem?

Comment: Are you running teh program with android/assets as the working folder?

Comment: @PhilAnderson Please respond on this!

Comment: @MduSenthil: I have nothing further to add. LibGdx can't find the file images/arial-15.fnt - That's the issue. Either the name's wrong, or it's in the wrong place, or the working folder is not set correctly.